# React setState and flux action update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I need a click function to do an update to the store through flux action and also update the state of the component.

Example: 
I have a form field with data for a story, and a state to say if the modal with the form is open.

```
// Initial state
return {
    story: this.props.story,
    modalIsOpen: true
}
```

--

```
// Click function to close the modal
closeModal: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    story.update(newStory)  // <== Flux action to update the story, which then updates this component 
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false})  // <== To actually close the modal
}
```

But it seems that whatever I put first runs and not the second one. So if I have `story.update(newStory)` first it executes that one but not `this.setState({modalIsOpen: false})`
and vice versa...

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to execute both?

Comment: Is `story.update()` throwing an exception?

Comment: Nope. It's all working. After page reload it has all the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need the `this.setState()` after your `story.update()`.
Probably after your action call, your component is re-rendered before the `this.setState()` is executed.
The flow should be:

- your component calls `story.update()`
- store listens to dispatcher and updates
- store emits change
- your component listen to change
- method inside component responding to store update does `setState( {modalIsOpen: false} )`.

Also, it seems that your `story` does not need to be in state: your component simply could simply render `this.props.story`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ES2015 class for creating React component (instead of `React.createClass()`) you might forget to bind event handler method to component's context. There are several ways to do it easily, here's a good tutorial: http://www.ian-thomas.net/autobinding-react-and-es6-classes/

I prefer using [autobind-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobind-decorator). With it you should fix your component to something like:

```
import autobind from "autobind-decorator";

class Foo extends React.Component {

  /* ... */

  @autobind
  closeModal: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    story.update(newStory)  // <== Flux action to update the story, which then updates this component 
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false})  // <== To actually close the modal
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually using React.createClass()